# trying to label the csv in python...how do i do this loading the legend in the comment in attached code

Tags: python, csv, pandas

**trying to label the csv in python...how do I do this loading the legend in the comment in attached code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import  tarfile
import os
%matplotlib inline
%autosave 20

tar = tarfile.open('C:\Users\mpiercy\projects\sc-sessions-09-25.csv.tgz', mode='r:gz')
tar.extractall('C:\Users\mpiercy\projects\sc-sessions-09-25')
df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\mpiercy\projects\sc-sessions-09-25\sc-sessions-09-25.csv', header=None)
df.head()
#site name, site id, start_time, end_time, energy_added, start_soe, end_soe
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to label the columns, which you can just do like this:

```
df.columns = ('site_name', 'site_id', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'energy_added', 'start_soe', 'end_soe')
```

Comment: this did not print out the labels and i got error mismatch

Comment: It's not so clear what you want to do. If there was a mismatch error its probably because there are a different number of columns than the number of labels you provided. We can't know how many columns there are in your data without seeing the data. Are you trying to label the columns? If the csv already has column labels in it's first row, then consider just getting rid of the argument <header=None>.

Comment: okay thanks yeah I think thats what it was...yes i am trying to label the columns and thanks for your help:)

Comment: how do i get them to print out?

Comment: Try print df.columns      or just df.columns without print